# failure to post PHP update to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, sql-update

i have a button i am trying to get where if i click it it updates the column 'gorg' in the table users to giver according to the current user (session) logged in. Everytime i click the button i get

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Here is the top of the php page (BTW i am 100% positive my DB Connection info is correct)

```
<?php
session_start();
include('src/sql_handler.php'); //this is where my DB Connection info is located
include('src/facebook_handler_core.php');
if(isset($_POST['submitgiver'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET gorg='giver' WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email'])."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

}

{
  if(isset($_SESSION['gorg'])=="Giver")
  {
    header('Location: picktreetype.php');
  }
  else if(isset($_SESSION['gorg'])=="Gatherer")
  {
    header('Location: gatherermap.php');
  }

}

?>
```

and now for the html

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

<input type="submit" class="button orange" name="submitgiver" value="Giver">

</form>
```

UPDATE:

heres the SQL_HANDLER

```
<?php


class MySQL_Con {

    private $host = 'localhost',

            $user = 'fruitfo1_admin',

            $pass = 'password',

            $db = 'fruitfo1_fruitforest',

            $_CON;



    function MySQL_Con() {

        $this->_CON = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);

        if(!$this->_CON)

            die(mysql_error());

        else {

            $select_db = mysql_select_db($this->db);

            if(!$select_db)

                die('Error Connecting To Database'.mysql_error());

        }

    }

    function End_Con() {

        mysql_close($this->_CON);

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Check your database connection, seems like you forgot to put a password , or you supplied a password when your database doesn't have one

Comment: There seems that you set a mysql password when you are trying to connect to database.. In your error message you can see that you don't have any password set for mysql connection

Comment: Sounds very much like an user access problem, not anything else.

Comment: Could you please attach "sql_handler.php" code, and the code you have used to create the database you are using where the table users is located?

Comment: i already said, i am 100% certain my passwords correct and so is all the other information, i think my problem lies within the if(isset($_POST

Comment: the ONLY reason i say i know my SQL_Handler isnt the issue, is because of two reasons, one its giving me a error saying im attempting to use ROOT as my user, when thats not declared anywhere in ANY of my coding, and two, all of my other scripts update correctly on seperate pages.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your connection setup doesn't include a password. Please post the `sql_handler` (WITH OBFUSCATED password) to be able to debug further.

If you're 100% positive it's correct, as you're saying, you can try explicitly passing sql handle to `mysql_query`.

Another note, `mysql_*` are deprecated, you really should consider switching to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Also, using `root` user for ANY kinds of web-applications is a no-no.

Comment: Okay so i believe my problem is simply that those if statements for the POST, arent even talking to my sql_handler, because im not using the username root or anything like that, therefore i believe its thinking that its not even pointing to the settings. could it be because i have my statements inside seperate brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Your DB doesn't have a password. Try this

```
  private $host = 'localhost',

        $user = 'fruitfo1_admin',

        $pass = '',

        $db = 'fruitfo1_fruitforest',

        $_CON;
```

Comment: My DB has a password, i use the same handler with many other pages that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

i found my issue, it did have to do with exactly what i thought it was. heres my updated code

```
if(isset($_POST['submitgiver'])) {
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "fruitfo1_admin";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "fruitfo1_fruitforest";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
$query = "UPDATE users SET gorg='giver' WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email'])."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

basically that IF statement that was attempting to POST wasnt linking back to my handler, so i placed the SAME db connection from the handler and carried it over inside the if isset statement and it worked!